# Why this select selects no rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to select a highest earner in 'IT' department, but I keep selecting no rows.
Salary and names are in table called employees while department_name is in a table named departments.
Can anyone please explain why does this select no rows and how should I do it?

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, salary, department_name
FROM employees
JOIN departments on departments.department_id = employees.department_id
WHERE salary = (SELECT max(salary) FROM employees WHERE department_name = 'IT');
```

Comment: please tag your sql engine.

Comment: please share sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why this select selects no rows?

Your query fails because there is no column `department_name` in the `employees` table. So your subquery does not do what you expect:

```
where salary = (SELECT max(salary) FROM employees WHERE department_name = 'IT');
```

If you want to do this with a subquery, you need to correlate it:

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name, e.salary, d.department_name
from employees e
inner join departments d on d.department_id = e.department_id
where 
    d.department_name = 'IT'
    and e.salary = (select max(e1.salary) 
                    from employees e1 
                    where e1.department_id = e.department_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dense_rank` if there are more than one highest earner for IT department.

```
select   
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    salary, 
    department_name
from
(
    select 
        first_name, 
        last_name, 
        salary, 
        department_name,
        dense_rank() over (partition by department_name order by salary desc) as rnk
    FROM employees e
    JOIN departments d
    on d.department_id = e.department_id
    where department_name = 'IT'
) val
where rnk = 1
```

Comment: this selects highest earners in all departments, while I need it to be only the one in IT

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT emp.first_name, emp.last_name, dempt.salary, dempt.department_name,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dept.department_name ORDER BY dept.salary DESC) AS SEQ
      FROM employees emp JOIN 
           departments dept 
           ON dept.department_id = emp.department_id
      WHERE dempt.department_name = 'IT'
     ) t
WHERE seq = 1;
```

If salary has ties then you can use `rank()` instead.

Comment: this however selects all highest earning employees, while I only need the one in IT